# Was this official picture ever commented on by the MLP:FiM show staff?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

As some people may know, the official MLP:FiM collectable card game is notorious for reusing show pictures / flash puppet / vectors from the actual show for the artwork used on most of the cards (something pretty common for MLP related merchandise - dolls and other toys box arts often use random collages of vectors images from the show). Yet in some rare occasions, original material was made just for the cards.

One of these original artworks catch my eye - Solar Flare / Nightmare Star, a "Nightmare" version of Celestia

[image]

This picture seem pretty different from any other original card image I know of for some reasons:
  - The character in the picture is "original" too, begin a version of an official character never actually featured in the show *so far*. The only other card featuring an original version of the character to my knowledge is the "Sonata Dusk pony version" card.
  - As far as the picture goes, it is not just a comic style drawing: it very closely resemble the art style from the show (and may as well be Flash-made) and contains very precise elements that seem to indicate that some work was put in it (for example, you can see the six Elements on the throne, the floor pattern seems to fit the show style and so on)

This has prompted some people to believe this picture is taken from some WIP art from a yet to come episode in the show. Another common theory is that this picture was intended to be used in yet another alternate timeline scene during season 5 finale, but that part of the episode was then dropped in the final cut.

Obviously, I am not looking for a complete explanation of the story behind this card, yet it seem strange that such an "out-of-place" picture was never commented on by an official source. As such, **I am interested in knowing if anyone from the show staff has ever commented on / given any explanation on this specific card (or at least if this was brought up in some convention or other such event)**.

---

**UPDATE**: In the season 7 episode "Royal Problems" a new evil version of Celestia is introduced during a dream sequence. However, the name give to this new character (Daydream) does not match the one on the card, and the two characters also have some evident visual differences. The background of the card does not match any scene in the episode, too.
For these reason I think the two characters should be considered as unrelated.

Comment: I can't find anything. I think I know who it's supposed to be though.

Comment: That character looks like BAD news. Better break out the rainbows immediately and ask questions later.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Yes, I know. I was mostly hoping for some reference been made during a show writer interview or something along the lines - stuff that most people won't know since they live far from pony con. and not every interview has been recorded. That said... if this happens to be from the 2017 movie, they can win the world record prize for "Most pre-empitive auto spoiler strike"...